# Condtional insert using a 'WHERE' from another table - not the one inserted into

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to be able to insert into one table but only if a condition is met on another table.

for example something like this

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (table_2_id,y,z) VALUES (123,2,3) 

WHERE (
(SELECT COUNT(table_2_id) FROM table_2 WHERE valid=1 and id=123)=1
)
```

Basically - I want to only insert into table_1 if the related record in table_2 is valid else it should fail.

is there a way to do this in one query or will I have to use some php+seperate query to do the check instead?

Comment: As for your question, look into *Stored Procedures*.

Comment: if I were your teacher (all of a sudden) I wouldn't be asking for help on a the issue? Maybe in South Africa the term does not carry the same meaning but in the UK it's an informal way to introduce a topic or question to anyone with a slight hint of urgency - 'okay, guys, I need your help on xyz' - (gals - just to be politically correct).

Comment: @KB, do you know table_2_id before executing the query? or do you want that from the inner SELECT statement?

Comment: @Aziz - yes, I know the id for table_2 before executing the query

Comment: @KB: Presenting a hint of urgency is not appropriate here. _Everybody_ wants their question answered as soon as possible; expressing an attempt to "jump the queue" as such is not endearing. Additionally, greetings are inappropriate here (especially extra-cordial ones like those you used, to people you don't know!) as SO is neither a message board nor chat, but a _knowledge resource_. Hope that helps.

Comment: (And "guys and gals" is most certainly **not** UK terminology. You watch too much yank TV!)

Comment: "okay, guys" - is used in the UK. I didn't use the term "guys & gals" - I added 'gals' in brackets as not everyone here is a guy. But that's fair enough, as you said, it's not a message board. However you'd have to edit a fair few comments throughout stackoverflow which where far more 'cordial' than what I used. But as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See whether this works for you:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (table_2_id,y,z) 
SELECT '123','2','3' 
FROM table_2 WHERE valid=1 and id=123
```